# Django reverse() ищет url pattern в основном приложении

Tags: python, django, url, reverse

Я использую reverse в приложении dialogs, пытаясь перейти после успешной обработки формы на следую страницу:

```
class CommonlyFilesUpload(FormView):
    form_class = CommonlyFilesForm
    template_name = 'dialogs/add_commonly_files.html'
    success_url = reverse('commonly_files')

    def get(self, request):
        form = CommonlyFilesForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('files_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['bot'])
            for f in files:
                CommonlyFile.objects.create(file=f, bot=form.cleaned_data['bot'])
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Но ничего не выходит, reverse почему-то ищет этот url pattern name в urls.py основного app:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'multibot_crm.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Как сказать reverse'у чтобы он искал в url.py нужного мне приложения? Пытался так:
success_url = reverse('dialogs:commonly_files')

Главный app (multibot_crm/urls.py):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('bots/', include('bot_manager.urls')),
    path('dialogs/', include('dialogs.urls'))
]
```

Приложение dialogs (dialogs/urls.py) в котором reverse() не хочет видеть паттерн с name = commonly_files:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('commonly_files/', views.CommonlyFiles.as_view(), name='commonly_files'),
    path('commonly_files/upload', views.CommonlyFilesUpload.as_view(), name='commonly_files_upload'),
]
```

Comment: Вот, дополнил только что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class CommonlyFilesUpload(FormView):
    form_class = CommonlyFilesForm
    template_name = 'dialogs/add_commonly_files.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('commonly_files')
```

Так должно сработать.